# Lucene: Indexsearcher: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, lucene

I get the following error message `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

with Lucene search method: `topDocs = searcher.search(booleanQuery, null, 100);`

when I'm trying to use the following implementation of MB25 Okapi Search (http://nlp.uned.es/~jperezi/Lucene-BM25)

```
  booleanQuery.add(new BM25BooleanQuery(current_tags[i], 
                        "tags",
                        new StandardAnalyzer()), 
                        BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);


            searcher = new IndexSearcher(INDEX_DIR);
            topDocs = searcher.search(booleanQuery, null, 100);
```

I'm using an old version of Lucene: Lucene 2.4.1 (I cannot upgrade!)

Can you help me to understand why I get such error ?

thanks

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.apache.lucene.search.Query.createWeight(Query.java:88)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$BooleanWeight.(BooleanQuery.java:185)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery.createWeight(BooleanQuery.java:360)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.Query.weight(Query.java:95)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.Searcher.createWeight(Searcher.java:185)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.Searcher.search(Searcher.java:136)
    at NVoting.(NVoting.java:159)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)

**Update**

BooleanQuery.java

```
weights.add(c.getQuery().createWeight(searcher));
```

Query.java

```
Weight weight = query.createWeight(searcher);
```

Comment: The full stack trace will tell you where the exception was thrown, and you can use that to investigate why.   There might even be a note why this exception is deliberately thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what is happening:

BM25BooleanQuery does not support the full Query API, which includes createWeight().
While you can use most Lucene Query types as atoms in building a BooleanQuery, this is not the case for BM25BooleanQuery. A BM25BooleanQuery has to stand on its own, using BooleanTermQuery-s as its building blocks.

If you stick to the instructions under "How to use it" in the URL you cited, the queries should work. AFAIK, there is no current solution to combining BM25 queries in Lucene into a larger query.

Please see [LUCENE-2091](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2091) and [LUCENE-2392](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2392) for the state of the art on BM25 in Lucene.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm actually combining BM25BooleanQuery with MatchAllDocsQuery because I want to get all documents as result and not only the relevant ones. Maybe I can get such output differently, you know how ? Maybe I can just combine the outputs of 2 different queries and not the queries themselves

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable option - you can combine the resulting ScoreDoc[] s; This way you do not have to combine the queries. You will probably need to wrap this in a little code that indicates the source query of a specific document (unless you do not need this distinction).

Comment: Not sure I got your last sentence. I actually need to remove from MatchAllDocsQuery results, the documents returned by BM25BooleanQuery to avoid duplicates. I guess I can use doc ids for that... Also, very important: my assumption is that if a doc is not returned by BM25 then its score is 0. (of course, I haven't set any limit to results). Could you confirm this ? thanks

Comment: One more thing: if I just pass the string "tag1 tag2 tag3" are the tags considered individually or not ? Or should I explicitly use BooleanTermQuery instead ? thanks

Comment: @user680406 - I do not completely get your intention. Do you want to only keep documents NOT matching the query (i.e. a negative match?) You do need ids for this, but better store separate ids. Do not use Lucene's doc ids, as they are liable to change. About your second question - it depends on your analyzer. I guess the second option is better.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [Query API](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_1/api/org/apache/lucene/search/Query.html#createWeight%28org.apache.lucene.search.Searcher%29) here, method you are calling at `org.apache.lucene.search.Query.createWeight(Query.java:88)` takes `Searcher` object as parameter, while you are passing a `Query` object.

Hope this direct you on the right way.

Comment: But then, shouldn't I get a compiling error ? Anyway, I've checked the code you mentioned and I've added the source to the question. It is correct, the searcher is always passed (and not the query).